# Check if item is missing before setting variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

So, I'm using code like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'php/parsedjson.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(index, val) {
             var product_name = data[index].Thing[0].Name;
             var pre_date = data[index].Another;
             var hazard_name = data[index].Something[0].Name;
             var remedies = data[index].Here[0].Name;
             var retailers = data[index].Hello[0].Name;
        });
    }
})
```

This works perfectly and sets all the variables (I'm then appending them to the DOM, but I left that out for simplicity).

The problem arises when one of the objects is missing one of these items. For example, this parses through 5 nested JSON objects supplied via the `AJAX`. One of them might be missing `data[index].Something[0].Name;`. Of course, this stops the `each` from running and throws an error.

Question: is there a shortcut to check if each of these item exists without having to do an `if/else` on each of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

retoheusser's answer is correct. However, unless your already using lodash I don't think anyone should be pulling an entire library into their project to use one function, especially when its an easy one to write.

Although there is not a native javascript shortcut for what you want, writing a short helper will do what you need.

```
function extract(obj, arry, def) {
  for (key in arry) {
    obj = obj[arry[key]];
    if (obj == null)
      return def || {};
  }
  return obj;
}
```

Given your code you could use it like this.

```
var product_name = extract(data, [index, 'Thing', 0, 'Name'], '');
```

I made a quick code pen example http://codepen.io/raykrow/pen/yMgyJq?editors=0012

**Update**

Or if you want to have a more attractive method call and don't need a default to be passed you could use this.

```
function extract(obj) {
  for (var i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    obj = obj[arguments[i]];
    if (obj == null)
      // return whatever best fits you for a
      // default value
      return {};
  }
  return obj;
}
```

To be used like:

```
var product_name = extract(data, index, 'Thing', 0, 'Name');
```

Code Pen example is http://codepen.io/raykrow/pen/PpWwVE

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use lodash's _.get function: https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#get